How to fix Snort++ 3.1.82.0 configuration file syntax error?
I'm trying to configure Snort++ 3.1.82.0 on Kali Linux, but I am encountering a syntax error with my snort.conf file. The error message I receive is:
ERROR: /etc/snort/snort.conf: can't load /etc/snort/snort.conf: /etc/snort/snort.conf:2: '=' expected near 'HOME_NET'
ERROR: /etc/snort/snort.conf: unknown logger console

Here's the content of my snort.conf file:
# Define the network variables (Snort++ 3.x syntax)
ipvar HOME_NET 192.168.1.0/24
ipvar EXTERNAL_NET !$HOME_NET
ipvar HTTP_PORTS [80,443,8080,8000,3128]

# Enable output plugins (for logging in Snort++)
output alert_fast: file=/var/log/snort/snort_alerts.txt
output log_tcpdump: file=/var/log/snort/tcpdump.pcap

# Rules file locations
var RULE_PATH /etc/snort/rules
include $RULE_PATH/local.rules
include $RULE_PATH/community.rules

# Enable preprocessors (optional, based on your needs)
preprocessor stream5_global: track_tcp yes, track_udp yes
preprocessor stream5_tcp: policy first, max_tcp 1000, timeout 180
preprocessor stream5_udp: max_udp 1000, timeout 180

# Set up detection engine parameters
config detection: search-method ac-bnfa
config alert_mask 0

# Set up network interface for monitoring
config interface: eth0

# Logging directory
config logdir: /var/log/snort

# Enable the snort rules (these are standard and can be customized)
include $RULE_PATH/icmp.rules
include $RULE_PATH/tcp.rules
include $RULE_PATH/http.rules



You're using a sample snort config file for snort 2.x. Snort 3 changed the config file format so that an = is now required for your variable assignments. First thing to check is the man pages, man snort.conf, see how the syntax has changed.

I don't understand this ERROR: /etc/snort/snort.conf: can't load /etc/snort/snort.conf: /etc/snort/snort.conf:2: unexpected symbol near '#'

finally it works!

@JoeyCadieux might want to post the working config file in an answer, then in 48 hours flag it as the answer to help other users.
